# Running Custom Jobs in parallet/distributed manner in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have a function and list of dictionaries. Each dictionary represent some configuration. Function takes one configuration and processes it.

I wanted to distribute tasks/jobs (each task consists of function and a configuration) over, say `n` servers and was wondering if this can be done using Apache Spark.

I googled resources but they were mostly around SQL, processing the data frame etc.

**Question:**

1. Can this be done using Apache Spark? if yes, can we also control number of cores that can be used by each task running on a server?
2. Is Apache Spark the right tool for this setup?

Edit: Seems like [Kubernetes](https://johndanielraines.medium.com/workload-parallelization-in-kubernetes-with-python-diy-style-1dfd32cf4366) is the right choice for such setups.